# 'Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ' error in Spark Scala code

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, out-of-memory

```
val data = spark.read
    .text(filePath)
    .toDF("val")
    .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())



    val count = data.count()



    val header = data.where("id==1").collect().map(s => s.getString(0)).apply(0)



    val columns = header
    .replace("H|*|", "")
    .replace("|##|", "")
    .split("\\|\\*\\|")


    val structSchema = StructType(columns.map(s=>StructField(s, StringType, true)))



    var correctData = data.where('id > 1 && 'id < count-1).select("val")
    var dataString = correctData.collect().map(s => s.getString(0)).mkString("").replace("\\\n","").replace("\\\r","")
    var dataArr = dataString.split("\\|\\#\\#\\|").map(s =>{ 
                                                          var arr = s.split("\\|\\*\\|")
                                                          while(arr.length < columns.length) arr = arr :+ ""
                                                          RowFactory.create(arr:_*)
                                                         })
    val finalDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(dataArr),structSchema)

    display(finalDF)
```

This portion of code giving error:

> Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

After hours of debugging mainly the part:

```
var dataArr = dataString.split("\\|\\#\\#\\|").map(s =>{ 
                                                          var arr = s.split("\\|\\*\\|")
                                                          while(arr.length < columns.length) arr = arr :+ ""
                                                          RowFactory.create(arr:_*)
                                                         })
    val finalDF = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(dataArr),structSchema)
```

causing the error.

I changed the part as

```
var dataArr = dataString.split("\\|\\#\\#\\|").map(s =>{
                                                          var arr = s.split("\\|\\*\\|")
                                                          while(arr.length < columns.length) arr = arr :+ ""
                                                          RowFactory.create(arr:_*)
                                                         }).toList
  val finalDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.makeRDD(dataArr),structSchema)
```

But error remains same. What should I change to avoid this?

When I ran this code is databricks spark cluster, particular job gives this Spark driver error:

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 45:0 was 792585456 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (268435456 bytes).

I added this portion of code:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.rpc.message.maxSize",Int.MaxValue)
```

but of no use.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: sorry.I read that and wont use again.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that

```
var dataString = correctData.collect().map(s => s.getString(0)).mkString("").replace("\\\n","").replace("\\\r","")
```

is the problem, because you collect (almost) all of the data to the driver, i.e. to 1 single JVM.

Maybe this line runs, but subsequent operations on `dataString` will exceed your memory limits. You should not collect your data! Instead, work with distributed "data structures" such as Dataframe or RDD.

I think you could just omit the `collect` in the above line

Comment: Code is failing if I remove collect . As i am pretty new in this domain, can you help me on this.What should I do exactly here